# Conditional probability with four random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume A, B, C, and D are i.i.d random variables and k is a fixed constant. I want to find $\textbf{P}(A < B, C, D | D = k)$. How would I go about getting this, in terms of the cdf of these random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean $\mathsf P(A<B,A<C,A<D\mid D=k)$

If the random variables are continuous then, since they are i.i.d with come CDF $F(\cdot)$, and pdf $f(\cdot)$:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A<B,A<C,A<D\mid D=k)
& = \int_{-\infty}^{k} \mathsf P(s<B) \, \mathsf P(s<C) \, f_A(s)\operatorname d s
\\
& = \int_{-\infty}^k (1-F(s))^2 f(s)\operatorname d s
\end{align}$$

For discrete integer random variables, with probability mass $p(\cdot)$ use:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A<B,A<C,A<D\mid D=k)
& = \sum_{s=-\infty}^{k-1} \mathsf P(s<B)\,\mathsf P(s<C)\, \mathsf P(A=s)
\\
& = \sum_{s=-\infty}^{k-1} (1-F(s))^2 p(s)
\end{align}$$

Adjust these bound to match the actual support of $A$.